# Qt - How to open a website in a particular browser

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, url, browser

I am coding one project, which needs to launch some webbrowsers with the given url.

I saw some QT examples, but they explained how to launch the default browser, not a particular browser.

Any helping suggestions will be appreciated.

**Edit1**:

Below is the code I use currently

```
QString temp="C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe";
process->start(temp.toStdString().c_str());
```

**Edit2**

Hi, I found that the problem is not in QProcess->start, Because it works perfectly for "explorer.exe", But not works, for executables which are in Program Files. 
   So I post a new question about it.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is something wrong with the path.Find the path of the executable that you are trying to use.

Comment: In response to your Edit2:
Ben Voigt has the right solution. you must `escape` space characters or else they are taken as arguments and not a path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know which browser you want to start and where they are located on the system (such as the default installation directories). You should be able to use [QProcess](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qprocess.html#details)

This can usually be done as the following:

`iexplore.exe http://www.locationOfUrl.com`

or

`//path/to/app/firefox.exe http://www.locationOfUrl.com`

Comment: +1 for QProcess. Check the doc. for QProcess::start method: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qprocess.html#start-2

Comment: @prabhakaran: a little bit more information is needed besides "It not works". Are you getting errors? Can you show some code? What have you tried exactly? Qt's QProcess is cross platform, so it 'should' work without a hitch (I have started processes before with arguments, which is exactly what you need to do...)

Comment: An example is here (right in QProcess documentation) for program and arguments. http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qprocess.html#details

Answer (score 2):

```
system("/path/to/the/browser \"http://www.the.com/url\"");
```

or [`spawn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx) instead of `system` (gives you control over environment variables, etc.)

Comment: @Ben The following didn't work                                    system("C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe");

Comment: @Ben The new console plrints some message, But I can't get it. Because the console closes within 2 min. Can you say how to get that message, or make the console to freeze for few mins.

Comment: @Ben I am sorry. I didn't try spawn, Can you say about the header file for this. Because it is showing that, that function not exists

Comment: @prabhakaran: Added link to spawn documentation.  The problem you're seeing is from having a space in the filename.  Try putting quotes around it, like `system("\"C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe\"");`  Same trick should also fix `QProcess::start`.